# Consulta basica de Base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

mi consulta es sobre como hacer un update para que actualice varias columnas al mismo tiempo, trabajo con java y mysql.

```
 stat.executeUpdate("Update producto set Prod_nombre= '"+Nom+"' , 
 Prod_precio="+pre+" , Prod_existencia="+exis+" , Prove_id= " +prove+"where 
 Prod_id="+cod);
```

Comment: Qué error tienes?? A simple vista me doy cuenta de que debes dejar un espacio entre las comillas y la palabra `where`. Lo tienes así `prove+"where` y debe ser de este modo `prove+" where`.

Comment: Gracias, tenia problemas en las comillas y el error que tu me identificastes.

Comment: Por nada, pero deberías mejor utilizar un `PreparedStatement` si vas a ejecutar una consulta a la cual se le pasan parámetros variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sería alo así por ejemplo..

stat.executeUpdate("Update producto set Prod_nombre='"+Nom+"', Prod_precio='"+pre+"', Prod_existencia='"+exis+"', Prove_id='"+prove+"' where Prod_id='"+cod+"' ");